# how to load my own data or online dataset in python for training CNN or autoencoder?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow, autoencoder

I'm trouble in a simple problem during loading dataset in python. I want to define function called `loading_dataset()` to use it in training auto encoder
my code is

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from urllib import urlretrieve
import cPickle as pickle
import os

import gzip
rom urllib import urlretrieve
import cPickle as pickle
import os
import gzip
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import theano
import lasagne
from lasagne import layers
from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
from nolearn.lasagne import visualize
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
#############################I tried to load data from open source
def load_dataset():
    url = 'ftp://ftp nrg.wustl.edu/data/oasis_cross-sectional_disc2.tar.gz'
    filename ='oasis_cross-sectional_disc2.tar.gz'
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        print("Downloading MNIST dataset...")
        urlretrieve(url, filename)
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
    X_train, y_train = data[0]
        X_val, y_val = data[1]
        X_test, y_test = data[2]
        X_train = X_train.reshape((-1, 1, 28, 28))
        X_val = X_val.reshape((-1, 1, 28, 28))
        X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, 1, 28, 28))
        y_train = y_train.astype(np.uint8)
        y_val = y_val.astype(np.uint8)
        y_test = y_test.astype(np.uint8)
        return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test
X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()
```

downloading MNIST dataset...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test = load_dataset()
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 6, in load_dataset
    urlretrieve(url, filename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 526, in open_ftp
    host = socket.gethostbyname(host)
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

this error appeared

I also tried to load data from my desktop using this code
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(pat):
for filename in files:
            fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:
                    s=np.load(f)
                data = f.read()
                    print data

but I failed to load data as values for X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, X_test, y_test 
I don't know if I should compress dataset in .pkl.gz or use different function for loading data
could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use keras to build network, here is the way to load mnist dataset

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
```

## load the MNIST data set, which already splits into train and test sets for us

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if you receive any error of downloading the dataset,
download dataset from https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz 
and put it in the folder called ~/.keras/dataset